# Can a nested loop be compressed into a single line comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, for-comprehension

I have a dictionary containing arrays of integers inside, I would like to be able to traverse all the arrays inside to get the maximum stored value. I have achieved all this with a double nested for loop as shown in the following code snippet:

```
my_dict = {
    'Key_1': [1, 42, 35],
    'Key_2': [12, 24],
    'Key_3': [80, 8, 58],
}
max_value=0
for values in my_dict.values():
    for v in values:
        if v > max_value:
            max_value = v
print(f'Max value is: {max_value}')
```

My doubt is if it could be compressed into a single line as shown in this non-functional code snippet:

```
max_value = (((v if v > max_value else 0) for v in values) for values in my_dict.values())
print(f'Max value is: {max_value}')
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can just do:

```
max(max(x) for x in my_dict.values())
```

Comment: Nice use of *Generator Expression* +1

Comment: I was afraid the expression would get ugly, but this is very readable.

Answer (score 1):

General flow -
`collection_c = [ (a,b) for a in collection_a for b in collection_b]`

Comment: Thank you so much! I will take that general flow in care!

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner without Python for loop:

```
max(max(my_dict.values(), key = max))
```

Result: 80

The key function i.e. key = max handles the case where the max is not the first item in each list.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I will take in care that key `key` too!